# Is the result of getBlockByNumber final?

Tags: go-ethereum, forks

Will the result of `getBlockByNumber` change due to the longest chain issue?

Say, I called `getBlockByNumber(100000)` now and got block A. 10 mins later, it turns out block A is not in the longest chain. Will the result of `getBlockByNumber(100000)` change then?

Answer (score 1):

Yep. This is only true for a few blocks close to the head block. For older blocks, it is probabilistically unlikely a re-org would happen.

Comment: Thanks @erkt. So you mean the result is not final, right? Btw, what's the recommended number of blocks to wait so I can be, say, 99.9% confident it won't re-org in the future.